# Segmentation fault in conversion operator (reference to member)

Tags: c++, reference, type-conversion

Why is this causing segmentation fault?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    std::string str;

    A(std::string const& pstr) : str(pstr)
    {}

    operator std::string const&() const { return str; }
};

bool operator==(A const& a, A const& b)
{ return std::string(a) == b; }

int main()
{
    A a1("hola"), a2("adios");

    std::cout << (a1 == a2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After all, the member `str` is still alive when doing the conversion.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7453471bc1af93e

Comment: So what happened when you loaded it into a debugger and single stepped through it, examining variables at each step. Seriously, does no-one know how to debug these days?

Answer (score 1):

Just edited your code and it worked for me:

```
return std::string(a) == std::string(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an recursive call to your `operator==`. Your constructor of `A` defines an implicit cast of `string` to `A`. To not allow that, add `explicit` to the constructor, but then you are missing a `operator==` for string and A;